# NoReverseMatch error Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

I am new to Django and cant seem to find a solution to my problem

I get the following error

```
Reverse for 'todo_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments

 '{'cid': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['todo/(?P<cid>)/']
    1   {% extends "base.html" %}
    2   {% block nav_title %} Company Batches {% endblock nav_title %}
    3   {% block content %}
    4     <div class="jumbotron">
    5   
    6         {% for obj in object_list %}
    7             <a href={% url 'todo_list' cid=obj.company.id%} class="href-nostyle">
    8                  <div class="container">
    9                     <div class="jumbotron" style="background:white">
    10                         <div class="text-center">
    11                             <h1>{{ obj.company }}<br>
    12                                 <small>{{ obj.job }}</small>
    13                             </h1>
    14                         </div>
    15                    </div>
    16                 </div>
    17            </a>
```

This template is located in an app named **company_batches** and I am attempting to navigate a user to the **todo** app using an href

my url tag is

```
{% url 'todo_list' cid=obj.company.id%}
```

my main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^batches/', include('company_batches.urls')),
    url(r'^todo/', include('todo.urls'), name='todo')
]
```

todo/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ToDoCreateView.as_view(), name='todo_create'),
    url(r'^(?P<cid>)/', ToDoListView.as_view(), name='todo_list'),
    ]
```

the relevant views.py

```
 class ToDoListView(ListView,):
    template_name = 'todo/todo_list.html'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super(ToDoListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       return context
    def get_queryset(self, cid):
       return ToDoList.objects.filter(company=self.cid)
```

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong, some guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: Your `cid` capture group in the regular expression is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to notice here.

**Regular expression, probably the actual issue here**
Capturing the `cid` in your `url regex` does not contain a proper capturing group. Since it's an ID, you should only capture digits with `\d+`

```
url(r'^(?P<cid>\d+)/', ToDoListView.as_view(), name='todo_list'),
```

**Closing url regex**
The current url does not contain a closing sign. If the url actually ends after the `/app/<id>/`, you should most likely close the regular expression with the dollar sign `$`.

```
url(r'^(?P<cid>\d+)/$', ToDoListView.as_view(), name='todo_list'),
```

**Namespace usage**
You are using a `name` while including the `todo` app urls. To use the namespace properly, you should drop the name in the `todo/` url and add
the `namespace` to the include.

```
url(r'^todo/', include('todo.urls', namespace='todo'))
```

Now in your template you can use the namespace

```
{% url 'todo:todo_list' cid=obj.company.id %}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, my regex wasn't correctly capturing the cid. Thanks for the detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is broken; it doesn't have any characters to match on. It looks like you want to capture a numeric PK, do it should be:

```
r'^(?P<cid>\d+)/
```